# Order email send and reply different email

Tags: magento-1.9

is it possible on magento make the email that sends the order be different with the reply email order from the client?

For example i wish when the client receives the order email, it shows email A that send him, but when he makes reply to the order email, it replys to email B.

Is it possible in magento? I cant find this specific option on the backend.

Comment: You want send Email with email_ID_1 and for customer reply you want to set reply ID as email_ID_2?

Comment: Yes, exactlly!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have to set `reply_to` parameter for message

I am not getting any shorter way...

**Below code is not TESTED**

First of all sales NEW ORDER EMAIL uses `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Mailer` which do not have `setReplyTo` function, so you have to create it

```
public function setReplyTo($email){  //added
     $this->setData('reply_to', $sender);
     return $this;
}
```

Now have to pass additional parameter to `sendTransactional` function of `core/email_template`

```
$emailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $this->getStoreId()))
                ->setQueue($this->getQueue())
                ->sendTransactional(
                    $this->getTemplateId(),
                    $this->getSender(),
                    $emailInfo->getToEmails(),
                    $emailInfo->getToNames(),
                    $this->getTemplateParams(),
                    $this->getStoreId(),
                    $this->getReplyTo()  //added
            );
```

As we have passed extra parameter to `sendTransactional` we have to change that function

First extend `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template` in your local module add function

```
public function sendTransactional($templateId, $sender, $email, $name, $vars=array(), $storeId=null, $reply_to=null) // $reply_to added
    {
        $this->setSentSuccess(false);
        if (($storeId === null) && $this->getDesignConfig()->getStore()) {
            $storeId = $this->getDesignConfig()->getStore();
        }

        if (is_numeric($templateId)) {
            $queue = $this->getQueue();
            $this->load($templateId);
            $this->setQueue($queue);
        } else {
            $localeCode = Mage::getStoreConfig('general/locale/code', $storeId);
            $this->loadDefault($templateId, $localeCode);
        }

        if (!$this->getId()) {
            throw Mage::exception('Mage_Core', Mage::helper('core')->__('Invalid transactional email code: %s', $templateId));
        }

        if (!is_array($sender)) {
            $this->setSenderName(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_' . $sender . '/name', $storeId));
            $this->setSenderEmail(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_' . $sender . '/email', $storeId));
        } else {
            $this->setSenderName($sender['name']);
            $this->setSenderEmail($sender['email']);
        }

        if ($reply_to) { //added
            $this->setSenderName($reply_to);
        }

        if (!isset($vars['store'])) {
            $vars['store'] = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId);
        }
        $this->setSentSuccess($this->send($email, $name, $vars));
        return $this;
    }
```